# sessionStorage won't expires objects

Tags: session, session-storage, expired-sessions

**Some details might useful:**

- ReactJS version 16.12.0
- Chrome version 78.0.3904.108
- Below is the setting of sessionStorage

[image]

**What happened**

Setting of sessionStorage was successful but after closing and reopening the tab key:value is still there. ***Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in sessionStorage.*** [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) ***not working.***
[image]

*Thank you for the answers.*

Comment: Did you try logging the login function to make sure it's not called by some mistake at tab load?

Comment: @NicolaeS I put console.log("==") after first open curly brace. Tried close and open, at tab load "==" not appear on the console. And still, the object is not clear.